# Catch API and 401 errors globally in React's router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I use `react` + `react-router` + `redux`. I would like to create a global thing for handling all the errors thrown in the app. Is it possible to catch also `API` call errors and `401` statuses?

I thoung about something like this in `Root.jsx`:

```
window.addEventListener("error", (e) => {});
```

It works for critical errors which I can log. But what if I want to serve some `API` errors?

**For example:** I want to save some grid data, but server thrown an error that 3 of 10 given rows weren't saved (I know it's a common problem and it should be resolved using transactions, but I use `Mongo` here `:P`). Now I want to show a simple dialog for a user which displays error message and 3 rows that weren't saved. What if I don't have permissions and the server throws `401` status code? Probably I would like to redirect user to index or login page.

This is some hipothetical example, because I want to simplify the thing I'm currently implementing.

I'm new in `React`, so I don't know the solutions for now, but if I programmed same thing in `Angular`, I would use `Angular's HTTP Interceptors` to solve my problem. I guess I need something similar here (or maybe it's some common solution for this?).

**[EDIT]**

Hmm. It seems I have found something that solves my problem: [fetch-intercept](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-intercept)

Anyway, do you know other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using ajax calls to access your API;

I would create a simple ajax wrapper that looks something like this;

```
AjaxWrapper = function(options){
    return $.ajax($.extend({}, options, {
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            if(jqXHR.status === 401){
                browserHistory.push('/unauthorized_route_handler');
            }
            options.error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    }))
}
```

Then you can simply use this wrapper to call your api, passing in an options object as you normally would to `$.ajax`.  Update the section within the `jqXHR === 401` as needed, or add handlers for 403 & 500 as well.